WPF - Size of Controls to fit in Nested Grid
Using WPF, I have a layout that is a series of nested grids, because my understanding is that that is better at preserving the look I want than using RowSpan. Each resulting Grid section is a region, that will be filled by some control, that changes depending on program settings. I am not creating these controls. I am creating templates, so that the people creating them have an understanding of how much space they have to work with.
I'm having trouble with the math, though, to give an accurate template size.
For example, I have a screen size of 1920x1200.
The first grid is split into two columns, 75* and 25*. A grid is placed in the first column, further split into three columns, 50*, 25*, and 25*. Each grid section has a margin of 5.
My understanding was that x* meant "this percent of the available screen size". So, a control in the second column of the second grid should have a width of 350 on my screen size.
First grid division: 1920 * 0.75 = 1440
Second grid division: 1440 * 0.25 = 360
Adjustment for margin: 360 - 10 = 350

But when I use that (with a width figured in a similar way) as the basis for a control and insert it into the correct grid division, it doesn't display correctly. It is squashed or stretched compared to what I am expecting.
I am clearly missing or misunderstanding something about how this works. Please help.
How should I be determining the correct size of these control templates?
Grid code:
<Grid>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="MainContent" Width="75*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="SidebarContent" Width="25*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Grid x:Name="MainContentGrid" Grid.Column="0">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ContentColumn1" Width="50*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ContentColumn2" Width="25*"/>
      <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ContentColumn3" Width="25*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Border x:Name="ContentColumn2Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="5">
      <local:ContentColumn2Control/>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</Grid>


Assuming the outer Grid has an ActualWidth of 1920, ContentColumn2Border will get a width of 350, as you expect. You can verify that by setting <Grid Width="1920"> and attaching a SizeChanged event handler to ContentColumn2Border.

Things that should not be stretched or clipped, generally show best using "Auto" Rows and Columns for "those" sections. Everything else is then made to "flow" around that content. If the "content" is the "wrong size", then you start resorting to explicit dimensions; or use a ViewBox or ScrollViewer. Still with the objective of getting the "main content" right first. (i.e. the "first cell")


My understanding was that x* meant "this percent of the available screen size". [...]

Your understanding is wrong.
x* meant "proportional distribution of available space that is left to distribute".
For e.g.
<Grid Width="1200">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" /> <!-- Width is 100 (1/6 of 600 that left) -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" /> <!-- Width is 300 (3/6 of 600 that left) -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" /> <!-- Width is 150 -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" /> <!-- Width is 450 (taken from width of Rectangle) -->
    <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" /> <!-- Width is 200 (2/6 of 600 that left) -->
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <Rectangle Grid.Column="3" Width="450" />
</Grid>

150 and 450 are taken explicitly, so from 1200 only 600 left. 1*, 3* and 2* sums up to 6*, so that 600 is divided into 6 parts and distributed proportionally. Size of the screen doesn't matter at all.
